# JPA Multiple commit within one transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Can I have multiple commits within one JPA transaction ? I'm using JPA with Hibernate. Correct me if I'm wrong but commit won't end the transaction ? Thanks for replay.

Comment: It depends on type of transaction management which you use (JTA type). It may be managed by container and also you can manage transactions manually.

Comment: I'm using Spring with local transaction:) I don't use server application. Apart from it I always use declarative transaction.

Comment: what do you mean "multiple commits" ? you mean tx.begin() ... tx.commit() then tx.begin() ... tx.commit() ????

Comment: So, you have answered on your question as I see. If you use declarative transactions you can't manage it manually. (You could use setSavepoint() by JDBC for example in other case).

Answer (score 4):

A [transaction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Transactions) is a *context* created within the execution environment that groups multiple commits (and/or DML operations on a database) in one execution unit - if one goes wrong, all the work done in this transaction context is discarded.

So in short: you can have multiple operations in one transaction, only when you commit that transaction those changes are applied to database.